# Decoding h264 / avc with OpenCV

Tags: javascript, node.js, opencv, h.264, broadway

I am trying to decode the h264 stream from [ws-scrcpy](https://github.com/NetrisTV/ws-scrcpy/) frame by frame to apply some computer vision operations. (ScrCpy is basically a mobile device application that broadcasts the device screen via h264. WS-ScrCpy is a web application that is able to receive and display the stream in a browser).

Since I need to do the computer vision operations in RGB space and on a server (via nodejs), I need to convert frames first from YUV to RGB format. Since JS-only implementations are slow, I am trying to get this done with [OpenCV](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs/).

Unfortunately, the decoded frames look like this:

[image: yuv -> RGB]

Here is what I do in more detail:

I use [Broadway](https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway) [Acv decoder](https://github.com/NetrisTV/ws-scrcpy/blob/master/vendor/Broadway/Decoder.js) to decode data (NALUs?- received via websocket) into frames. Then I use OpenCV to convert YUV frames to RGB.

```
import Avc from './vendor/Broadway/Decoder'
//...
this.avc.onPictureDecoded = (buffer: Uint8Array, width: number, height: number) => {
  const mYUV = new cv.Mat(h + h / 2, w, cv.CV_8UC1, buffer)
  const mRgb = mYUV.cvtColor(cv.COLOR_YUV420p2BGR)
  cv.imwrite('./del/test.png', mRgb)
}
```

The fact that the image size of the resulting Mat object is correct, tells me that I am doing something right.
But as you can see there also is obviously something wrong.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: Sorry that i cant help you with that, but allow me to give you another option: why not pipe it through ffmpeg? ffmepg is realy great for multimedia work and can work with streams (stdin/stdout)

Comment: I see you are using OpenCV just for color conversion, and not for decoding the video. Try `COLOR_YUV2RGB_I420`. In case it's not working, please post `mYUV` as grayscale image  - use `cv.imwrite('./del/yuv420.png', mYUV)` and add `yuv420.png` to your post. We better verify that the decoded image is valid before converting to BGR...

Comment: Agree with both comments above. It seems like something unexpected is happening and we're not sure why. You clearly know what you are doing, but personally I would go back to basics to confirm that all of my assumptions are correct. 1) save the frame before modifying to color information. Check with `file` or another utility to confirm the format of the frame, maybe frame is not a png as expected (and can't find any documentation)

Comment: 2) try the [Broadway RGB decoding option](https://github.com/mbebenita/Broadway#options-1). I know you want to do this using OpenCV but this would help eliminate OpenCV and the color change logic as the culprit 3) explicitly set [the encoding](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy#encoder)? Maybe it's not actually using H.264. Also you could test a different (simpler) encoding

Comment: Streaming to ffmpeg also seems like a great option, for debugging or for final solution. It's fast, available for every platform, supports basically every known encoding, and can output frames to png, jpg, or bmp.

Comment: @Marc I don't want to add ffmpeg to my project because I already package opencv (it's a desktop application) and opencv uses ffmpeg as a backend. So in theory opencv should have everything on board to get the job done.

Comment: Let us know if you get any more info!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to decode the image. @Rotem you mentioned that I am using OpenCV just for color conversion, but I wouldn't know how to "decode" the image otherwise.

Comment: @Codebling how can I "save the frame" if I can't even load it into a datastructure? Or should I just write the whole buffer to disk? Isn't there some png header missing then?

Comment: I know OpenCV, but I don't know JavaScript... Decoding NALU by NALU is only going to work when all frames are key frames (otherwise, the first decoded frame is valid only after the first key frame, and the decoder should never miss a frames / NALU between key frames). I can't help you with that...

Comment: @Rotem I believe the decoder is stateful, and is only passing decoded frames

Comment: @stoefln we don't know what format Broadway is returning in the Buffer (there is basically no documentation). It definitely wouldn't be a png (no header, like you said), but dumping the raw Buffer and inspecting it in hex, or trying to open it as a "raw image" using an photo editor, would help assess the format. Maybe fixing the image is a matter of changing the Mat type to a different value ([one of the ones here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d1b/group__core__hal__interface.html))

Comment: Could the green image be parts of many images *(such as their tops)*? Maybe the program can't handle to send really large strings so that they only sent parts of them?